# JS Circular countdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have a question!
I want the below circle to be filling with different color "onComplete" and also if it's possible to not start with autoplay but onclick.
Could you please someone help me?????
The main idea is when you click the circle it begins a countdown-waiting to submit your answer, so i want the circle to turn the same color as the progress bar.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="countdown"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       $("#countdown").countdown360({
     radius      : 60,
     seconds     : 3,
     fontColor   : '#FFFFFF',
     autostart   : false,
     onComplete  : function () { console.log('done') }
       }).start()
      </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

```html
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = "countdown360",
    defaults = {
      radius: 15.5,                    // radius of arc
      strokeStyle: "#477050",          // the color of the stroke
      strokeWidth: undefined,          // the stroke width, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fillStyle: "#8ac575",            // the fill color
      fontColor: "#477050",            // the font color
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",        // the font family
      fontSize: undefined,             // the font size, dynamically calulated if omitted in options
      fontWeight: 700,                 // the font weight
      autostart: false,                 // start the countdown automatically
      seconds: 3,                     // the number of seconds to count down
      label: ["second", "seconds"],    // the label to use or false if none
      startOverAfterAdding: true,      // Start the timer over after time is added with addSeconds
      onComplete: undefined
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (!this.settings.fontSize) { this.settings.fontSize = this.settings.radius/1.2; }
    if (!this.settings.strokeWidth) { this.settings.strokeWidth = this.settings.radius/4; }
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this._init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {

    extendTimer: function (value) {
      var seconds = parseInt(value),
          secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime())/1000);
      if ((this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + seconds) <= this.settings.seconds) {
        this.startedAt.setSeconds(this.startedAt.getSeconds() + parseInt(value));
      }
    },

    addSeconds: function (value) {
      var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime())/1000);
      if (this.settings.startOverAfterAdding) {
          this.settings.seconds = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed) + parseInt(value);
          this.start();
        } else {
          this.settings.seconds += parseInt(value);
        }
    },

    start: function () {
      this.startedAt = new Date();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI*3.5, true);
      this._drawCountdownLabel(0);
      this.interval = setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this._draw, this), 1000);
    },

    stop: function (cb) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      if (cb) { cb(); }
    },

    _init: function () {
      this.settings.width = (this.settings.radius * 2) + (this.settings.strokeWidth * 2);
      this.settings.height = this.settings.width;
      this.settings.arcX = this.settings.radius + this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.settings.arcY = this.settings.arcX;
      this._initPen(this._getCanvas());
      if (this.settings.autostart) { this.start(); }
    },

    _getCanvas: function () {
      var $canvas = $("<canvas id=\"countdown360_" + $(this.element).attr("id") + "\" width=\"" +
                      this.settings.width + "\" height=\"" +
                      this.settings.height + "\">" +
                      "<span id=\"countdown-text\" role=\"status\" aria-live=\"assertive\"></span></canvas>");
      $(this.element).prepend($canvas[0]);
      return $canvas[0];
    },

    _initPen: function (canvas) {
      this.pen              = canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.pen.lineWidth    = this.settings.strokeWidth;
      this.pen.strokeStyle  = this.settings.strokeStyle;
      this.pen.fillStyle    = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.textAlign    = "center";
      this.pen.textBaseline = "middle";
      this.ariaText = $(canvas).children("#countdown-text");
      this._clearRect();
    },

    _clearRect: function () {
      this.pen.clearRect(0, 0, this.settings.width, this.settings.height);
    },

    _secondsLeft: function(secondsElapsed) {
      return this.settings.seconds - secondsElapsed;
    },

    _drawCountdownLabel: function (secondsElapsed) {
      this.ariaText.text(secondsLeft);
      this.pen.font         = this.settings.fontWeight + " " + this.settings.fontSize + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
      var secondsLeft = this._secondsLeft(secondsElapsed),
          label = secondsLeft === 1 ? this.settings.label[0] : this.settings.label[1],
          drawLabel = this.settings.label && this.settings.label.length === 2,
          x = this.settings.width/2;
      if (drawLabel) {
        y = this.settings.height/2 - (this.settings.fontSize/6.2);
      } else {
        y = this.settings.height/2;
      }
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft + 1, x, y);
      this.pen.fillStyle  = this.settings.fontColor;
      this.pen.fillText(secondsLeft, x, y);
      if (drawLabel) {
        this.pen.font = "normal small-caps " + (this.settings.fontSize/3) + "px " + this.settings.fontFamily;
        this.pen.fillText(label, this.settings.width/2, this.settings.height/2 + (this.settings.fontSize/2.2));
      }
    },

    _drawCountdownShape: function (endAngle, drawStroke) {
      this.pen.fillStyle = this.settings.fillStyle;
      this.pen.beginPath();
      this.pen.arc(this.settings.arcX, this.settings.arcY, this.settings.radius, Math.PI*1.5, endAngle, false);
      this.pen.fill();
      if (drawStroke) { this.pen.stroke(); }
    },

    _draw: function () {
      var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime())/1000),
          endAngle = (Math.PI*3.5) - (((Math.PI*2)/this.settings.seconds) * secondsElapsed);
      this._clearRect();
      this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI*3.5, false);
      if (secondsElapsed < this.settings.seconds) {
        this._drawCountdownShape(endAngle, true);
        this._drawCountdownLabel(secondsElapsed);
      } else {
        this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds);
        this.stop();
        this.settings.onComplete();
      }
    }

  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    var plugin;
    this.each(function() {
      plugin = $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);
      if (!plugin) {
        plugin = new Plugin(this, options);
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, plugin);
      }
    });
    return plugin;
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: library : https://github.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360/blob/master/src/jquery.countdown360.js for informations

Answer (score 1):

The library seems to be a little buggy. The countdown is displayed only on start, which is not allow to launch him by a click.

I've made some moves in it to allow that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYBwrE?editors=101

In detail, I have moved:

```
  this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI*3.5, true);
  this._drawCountdownLabel(0);
```

from the start function to the init function.

Comment: OMG! You are amazing thank you so much! I'm so happy! I'm just a designer so js is not my thing! But could you help me with the different color filling "onComplete" ?